# javascript & HTML Cost Calculator - Value of Carpet x Size of Room

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to create a cost-calculator for my friend's carpet business website.

I don't know how to get both input fields and multiply them together to get the result/cost.

I'd like it so that a client chooses a carpet type - with cost per m2 associated with it

Then choose the size of the room.

The result would be the `cost per m2` x `m2 of the room`.

I've created this horror show so far, it works for the first part - cost per m2, not the multiplication or size of room part though.

```
`<select id="classSelect" onchange="aFunction()">
<option value="0">Choose Flooring Type</option>
<option value="1">Vinyl</option>
<option value="2">Thick Carpet</option>
<option value="3">Standard Carpet</option>
<option value="4">Class 4 Cost 4</option>
<option value="5">Class 5 Cost 5</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onchange="bFunction()">
<option value="0">Choose Size</option>
<option value="3">3 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="5">5 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="10">10 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="15">15 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="20">20 meters squared</option>
</select>


<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function aFunction(){
classCost = Number(document.getElementById("classSelect").value);
fee = 5;
if (classCost > 0){
    total = classCost + fee;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
}else{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Select Class");
}
}
</script>`
```

Comment: While we appreciate you are just starting out, this site is best for specific questions that aren't easily answered by many web or tutorial references that are available for free. This is just too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

*"I don't know how to get both inputted fields and multiply them together to get the result/cost."*

It's not a full implementation of what you want, it's just a good point to start. Here I get values from two inputs, multiply them and write final value to the `h1` tag (I didn't add any checks for `NaN` and so on, it's just a starter for you):

```js
function calculate() {
  var result = parseInt(document.getElementById('one').value) * parseInt(document.getElementById('two').value);
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<input id="one">
<input id="two">
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<h3>Result of multiplication: </h3>
<h1>0</h1>
```

### Update

*"Any idea please what I'm missing here - jsfiddle.net/v1ncjkpw "*

You just forgot to change function name and insert `h1` tag. `onchange` event doesn't fire on jsfiddle for some reason (it's OK for jsfiddle), so here is the snippet with updated code:

```js
function calculate() {
  var result = parseInt(document.getElementById('classSelect').value) * parseInt(document.getElementById('size').value);
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<select id="classSelect" onchange="calculate()">
    <option value="0">Choose Flooring Type</option>
    <option value="1">Vinyl</option>
    <option value="2">Thick Carpet</option>
    <option value="3">Standard Carpet</option>
    <option value="4">Class 4 Cost 4</option>
    <option value="5">Class 5 Cost 5</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onchange="calculate()">
    <option value="0">Choose Size</option>
    <option value="3">3 Meters Squared</option>
    <option value="5">5 Meters Squared</option>
    <option value="10">10 Meters Squared</option>
    <option value="15">15 Meters Squared</option>
    <option value="20">20 meters squared</option>
</select>

<h1>0<h1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...any idea please what I'm missing here - https://jsfiddle.net/v1ncjkpw/

Answer (score 0):

As what i understood from you question is that you want to multiple both selected values like (class+5) * size

```js
function calculate(){
 var classCost = Number(document.getElementById("classSelect").value);
  if (classCost === 0){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Select Class";
    return; 
  }
  
  var roomSize = Number(document.getElementById("size").value);
  if (roomSize === 0){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Select Size";
    return; 
  }
  
  var total = (classCost + 5) * roomSize;
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total Cost is " + total;
 
}
```

```html
<select id="classSelect" onchange="calculate()">
<option value="0">Choose Flooring Type</option>
<option value="1">Vinyl</option>
<option value="2">Thick Carpet</option>
<option value="3">Standard Carpet</option>
<option value="4">Class 4 Cost 4</option>
<option value="5">Class 5 Cost 5</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onchange="calculate()">
<option value="0">Choose Size</option>
<option value="3">3 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="5">5 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="10">10 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="15">15 Meters Squared</option>
<option value="20">20 meters squared</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Please see the solution on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malik_nasir/jjfwpkut/)